# Socket.io Error on server

Tags: php, sockets, socket.io

I am tried to use socket io on the live server and I got this error.

```
polling-xhr.js:264 GET http://sub.domain.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MFUVMS5 net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

But on my local server, the files worked perfectly. I am working with socket.io and PHP.

Here are my codes:

**server.js**

```
var socket = require('./node_modules/socket.io');
var express = require('./node_modules/express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// server active console view
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // show new added online user
    socket.on('now_online', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('now_online',{
            id: data.id,
            name: data.name
        });
    });
});
```

**main.js**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000');
socket.on('new_online_user', function (data) {
    if (login_id != data.online_user) {
        $('#contacts-list .contact[data-chat='+data.online_user+']'+' .contact-status').addClass('online');
    }
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

I was searching in google and StackOverflow about this issue but those solved didn't work for me.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Is port 3000 is open for socket on web server?

Comment: "I am working with socket.io and PHP". You have client and server code in Javascript, is the PHP tag accidental, or is something missing from this question?

Comment: Please check if the node modules installed  in the server `var socket = require('./node_modules/socket.io');
var express = require('./node_modules/express');`

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Yes port is open for socket .io

Comment: @mike42 Hi, I am handling server request by Ajax. I think, I didn't anything in my question.

Comment: @AramGrigoryan Hi, Yes node modules installed in the server and file also connected with the server.js file. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting using only domain without `http` like:

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname+':3000', {transports: ["websocket", "xhr-polling", "htmlfile", "jsonp-polling"]});
```

It will automatically become `ws://sub.domain.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MFUVMS5`. I'm using similar to this and working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solved but it not worked. Same error  :(

Comment: Hi, Now I got this, 
WebSocket connection to 'ws://sub.domain.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established and socket.io not working.

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/798 . Might get some help.

Comment: I used pm2 to run the server in the background and at this moment I remove the server from pm2 and run the server using 'node server.js'.

Comment: I removed pm2 from the server and tried to use 'node server.js' and also your config and still got above error and aslo thank you so much